# Mongo schema building failing with error 8: '24: Too many open files' on local db. ulimit and similar methods failing

Tags: mongodb, macos, unix, macos-high-sierra

I am trying to run a script to build a mongo schema on a local mongo database but half way through the script fails with the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: 
Command failed with error 8: '24: Too many open files' on server 127.0.0.1:27017.
The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "24: Too many open files", "code" : 8 }
```

I am on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.3.  I have tried to do the fixes shown here: https://superuser.com/questions/433746/is-there-a-fix-for-the-too-many-open-files-in-system-error-on-os-x-10-7-1 .  When I do ulimit -n and an amount over 1000 it fails without sudo and when I do the same command with sudo it does not change the limit to over 1000.  I have also tried closing down a lot of running applications, setting the kern.maxfiles=20480
kern.maxfilesperproc=18000 values.  I am running mongo in the same shell I run the ulimit command in.  Does anyone have any idea what is going on or how to resolve this?  I formerly was able to complete the building of the mongo schema successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue. I installed via brew.
if I start mongod with as brew service it is working fine.

Brew services start mongodb@3.6

I am still not sure about the root cause of failure if I run through command line.